# Android auto update using playstore

Tags: android

I have an Android application that is uploaded to play store.
I need to use playstore to update the app, that is when there is an update for the app, I should send the user to the play store.
My problem is that there is always an "Open" button in play store, and I never see "Update" button, even if I have two different versions, one on the phone and the other on the play store.
And also please one more question, is this the best way to update the app? Is it the standard way?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Theres a few steps you'll need to follow in order to update your application on google play store, at first Version your application :

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html

2nd step is to sign the application for the first time :

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

and the 3rd step is to update the version of your application on play store :

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en

in the last link you will guidance on how to check the application signature and if they match the previous version signature.

Comment: thanks for replying, I already did the first two steps, how do I know if the app is installed in the system partition? regarding the signature, i sign my app with the same key every time

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!
My mistake, I was trying to check the update without signing the application (I copied it directly from the bin!)

Thanks,